# RecyclerView add Item animation

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

I am currently working on adding a income animation for RecyclerView items. I want it just likes the Google+ Android App. Here is my code snippets:

anim/up_from_bottom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="60%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

and in the Adapter class I add the function `startAnimation(itemHolder.itemView, position);` in the funciton`onBindViewHolder`

```
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ...
    startAnimation(holder.rootView, position);
}
```

the startAnimation() is like this:

```
protected void startAnimation(View view, int position) {
    if (position > lastPosition) {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.up_from_bottom);
        view.startAnimation(animation);
        lastPosition = position;
    }
}
```

It seems looks like the Google+ Android App's list animation, but it has a bug, when I scroll fast, it animate not perfect, such as it seems that the first position and the current postion perform the animation at the same time.

I just want the animation like Google+, how can I fix it, or there has any other way.

I hava try [recyclerview-animators](https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators), it's a great lib, but I still do what I want.

Any help please! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "bug" occurs when you scroll fast because the animation on the viewholder is still running when it is scrolled out of the display and you are binding a new animation to the viewholder when the recyclerview recycles it.

You should override `onViewDetachedFromWindow` and clear the animation on the view in the method.

This will ensure that any animation that is running on the view will be cleared before it is sent to the recycler for resuse, and you can safely run a new animation on the view.